# What is this weed looking thing in my crawlspace?

Tags: mold, crawlspace, fungus, weeds

I had some plumbers go into my crawl space for some repairs, and were freaked out by some weed like growth which is very white in color. They asked that some water damage restoration team come out to clean it up. Those guys came in and looked at it and said it is just some weeds covered with efflorescence. But I am still not a 100% because they really did not go to the spot with the actual weeds - rather they looked close to the crawlspace entrance and found some efflorescence and then looked at my plumber's photo and extrapolated what it could be. While I am waiting for another technician to give me a second opinion, I thought I will pose the question here to see if anyone has any information about this.

[image: Weeds]

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe we could have a closeup of the plant?

Comment: IT's some type of plant. Because it in in the dark there is no useful need for chlorophyl, so the plants have no green color.

Comment: Perhaps a fungus, i.e. mycelium that grows on debris or chunks of wood in the soil during the damp season. Perhaps root sprouts from a tree growing outside the building. Roots sometimes spread astonishing distances from the mother plant.

Comment: It would be just salt based on crystalline formation

Comment: where do you live, ? near a ocean

Comment: Close-up photo would help hugely. For that matter, feeding a close-up photo into an image websearch might identify it for you; I've been using Lens to help with plant ID for years

Comment: @HoneyDo I will try to get some when I manage to go in there this weekend.

Comment: @Ruskes - yes about 3 miles from the ocean in San Diego, though up in the edge of a canyon

Comment: Salt deposits ..